# Determine the running time ( O-Notation ) of the following algorithm " fun "

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

Assumptions:

I should mentioned that every addition and multiplication considered as one time unit. Moreover it holds that $ n = 2^k$, k is odd.

My idea:

In my lecture I found the Master-Theorem and it seems that we can use this to solve the Question above. In case that you don't remember the Theorem:

> Let $ \alpha \geq 1 $, $\beta > 1 $, $ C > 0 $ constants and $f(n)$ a positive function. Moreoever $ c_1(n),...,c_\alpha(n)$ functions with $|c_i(n)| \leq C $ for all $ 1 \leq i \leq \alpha $ and $ n \in \mathbb{N}$. If $T(n) $ is a function with $T(1) = 0$ and for $ n \geq 1 $ the following recursion
>
> $ T(n) = T(\frac{n}{\beta + c_1(n)}) + ...+  T(\frac{n}{\beta + c_\alpha(n)}) + f(n)$ holds, then
>
> $ T(n) = \Theta(n^{log_{\beta}\alpha}) $, if $f(n) = O(n^{log_{\beta}\alpha- \varepsilon})$ for a $\varepsilon > 0$.
>
> $ T(n) = \Theta(f(n)\log(n))$, if $f(n) = O(n^{log_{\beta}\alpha}(\log(n)^{\delta}))$ for a $\delta \geq 0$
>
> $ T(n) = \Theta(f(n))$, if $f(n) = \Omega(n^{log_{\beta}\alpha + \varepsilon})$  for a $ \varepsilon > 0$.

But how can I use this theorem exactly? Thank you for your effort.

Comment: As written, it looks like nonsense to me, as Fun appears to be a function of $n$ arguments, but on line 6, it's called with $n/4$ arguments. Presumably this is really defining a class of algorithms that work on argument-lists whose length is two times a multiple of $4$. Sigh. I weep for my field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $H(n)$ denote the largest number of operations involved in evaluating $fun$ on any set of $n$ inputs, where $n = 2 \cdot 4^k$ for some $k$.  Then

\begin{align}
H(2) &\le 2 & \text{lines 2, 3, 4, 15} \\
H(n) &\le 2 \cdot H(\frac{n}{4}) + 3 \cdot \frac{n}{4} & \text{for $n > 2$} \text{, by lines 6, 7, for the first term,  8, 9, 12 for the second}
\end{align}
which frankly is probably not what you're supposed to get, because (1) incrementing the index may not count as an addition (although I've treated it as one), and/or (2) assigning a value to a variable should probably count as a unit of work as well. And of course, indexing an array involves a multiply-and-offset (or not, depending on whether your compiler optimizes cleverly or not) too. So that factor of $3$ in the second inequality could be as large as $15$ or so.

Anyhow, in your case $\alpha$ is two, because there are two recursive calls. And $\beta$ is $4$, and $c_1(n) = c_2(n) = 0$, so you can pick $C = 1$. Finally, your function $f$ is $f(n) = \frac{3}{4}n$, which is in $O(n)$ (and the difference between $\frac{3}{4}$ and $\frac{15}{4}$ isn't going to matter, so you can mostly ignore the worries of the preceding paragraph). Now 
$$
\log_\beta (\alpha) = \log_4(2) = \frac{1}{2}
$$
and your $f(n)$ is not in $O(n^\frac{1}{2})$ --- not even close --- so conclusions 1 and 2 are irrelevant, and you're in case 3. You can say that 
$$
H(n)
$$
is in $\Theta(f(n)) = \Theta(n)$.